# Grails test log.debug or println to output not working with -echoOut

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j

Using legacy grails 2.2
In the config environments I have set the debug to be app wide

```
test{
   log4j={
      root{
          error 'stdout'
          debug 'stdout'
      }
      debug 'grails.app'

    }
}
```

I have the parameter

```
-echoOut
```

in the command line options.

But if I run a test case with a log.debug somewhere in the chain, I get nothing in the console or in the generated report.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding your apps package name to **debug 'grails.app'** like **debug 'stdout': ['grails.app', 'your.package']**